# Laravel 5.2 : MethodNotAllowedException

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've defined the following route in Laravel:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {
    Route::post('login', [
        'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@login',
        'as' => 'auth.login',
    ]);
});
```

And I'm using Postman to send a request like this (you can also see the results):

[image]

Why am I getting a MethodNotAllowed exception????
I also tried creating a form in an empty html file, with the method set to post. but got the same results.

### EDIT

If i add a route::get that shows a login form, after the post request in Postman it shows that login form.

[image]

### EDIT 2:

output of `php artisan route:list` for our route entries:

```
+--------+----------+--------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI          | Name                | Action                                             | Middleware |
+--------+----------+--------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /            | guest.home          | App\Http\Controllers\GuestController@index         |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | a/dashboard  | admin.dashboard     | Closure                                            |            |
|        | POST     | api/login    | auth.login          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login     |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/login    | auth.login          | Closure                                            |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/logout   | auth.logout         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@getLogout | jwt.auth   |
|        | POST     | api/register | auth.register       | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@register  | jwt.auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD | m/dashboard  | moderator.dashboard | Closure                                            |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | pu/dashboard | premium.dashboard   | Closure                                            |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | u/dashboard  | user.dashboard      | Closure                                            |            |
+--------+----------+--------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

### EDIT3

One more curious thing. If i set the method to Route::any, I get rid of the exception, but then I can't access the post parameters. i.e. I don't have any post parameters.

### EDIT 4:

If I add a route::get and show the login view there and send the login credential, it works. But not in Postman.

Comment: Did you try `php artisan route:clear`?

Comment: Nope. Let me try that.

Comment: Yup, i tried it and it didn't work. I added a Route::get to the routes file, in which I show a view with a login form. And now when I send the post request in postman i get that login form which is bound to the get route.

Comment: Very weird. Try this command `php artisan route:list` You will see all registerde routes. Is `POST` `/api/login` there?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, and it shows exactly what I expect to see. Dude weird doesn't even begin to explain this :(((((( It's not like this is the first time I'm defining and using routes in Laravel.

Comment: try to change route name cause you have 2 routes with the same name `auth.login`

Comment: I totally removed that other route to no effect. Thanks anyways

Comment: Do other post routes in the same controller work?

Comment: As a matter of fact, i tried to add another one ( register ) and it produced the same results. But thanks, it was a good point. I'll try to test a post route on another controller. Who knows, maybe that works

Comment: @Fester It elicits the same behavior on other controllers.

Comment: @mnVoh so you can't access post routes in general in your application?

Comment: @Fester: Yup, that's it

Comment: Another thing you could try is creating a very basic view and sending your request through a HTML form instead, don't forget using a CSRF token!

Comment: I've tried that and I get the same exception. And by the way, I've disabled the VerifyCSRFToken middleware.

Comment: @Fester : Actually if I send the data to the post route through a view, it works. The first time I tried that, it was a plain html file on my desktop.

Comment: @mnVoh might just be a postman issue then, if posting from a view works your problem is kind of solved isn't it?

Comment: I think so, but now there's the question why Postman doesn't work properly? :-)

Comment: try x-www-form-urlencoded instead of form-data in postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the problem was with Postman3. I'm using Advanced REST Client now, and it works alright. Postman would send GET requests no matter what method I chose.

Answer (score 1):

Use x-www-form-urlencoded instead of form-data in postman, See the difference below.

[image]

**form-data**

multipart/form-data is the default encoding a web form uses to transfer data. This simulates filling a form on a website, and submitting it. The form-data editor lets you set key/value pairs (using the key-value editor) for your data. You can attach files to a key as well. Do note that due to restrictions of the HTML5 spec, files are not stored in history or collections. You would have to select the file again at the time of sending a request.

[image]

**urlencoded**

This encoding is the same as the one used in URL parameters. You just need to enter key/value pairs and Postman will encode the keys and values properly. Note that you can not upload files through this encoding mode. There might be some confusion between form-data and urlencoded so make sure to check with your API first.